# Project Euler #11: Python solution not working

Tags: python

> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in any direction
>   (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

http://projecteuler.net/problem=11

I have created two dimensional tuple, LIST from the numbers.

> LIST = ((8, 2, 22, ....), (49, 49, 99, ....) ...)

Here is my solution. I am not able to figure out the logical flaw.

**(Edit)**: My answer is 51267216 but not correct.

```
# For every number check diagnolly, down and right if the product exceeds max_product. 
# Ignore the exception(OutOfBounds) if encountered.
max_product = 0

for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
            temp = 1
            try: 
                for k in range(4):
                    temp = temp * LIST[i][j+k]
                if (temp > max_product):
                    max_product = temp
            except:
                pass

            temp = 1
            try: 
                for k in range(4):
                    temp = temp * LIST[i+k][j]
                if (temp > max_product):
                    max_product = temp
            except:
                pass

            temp = 1
            try:
                for k in range(4):
                    temp = temp * LIST[i+k][j+k]
                if (temp > max_product):
                    max_product = temp
            except:
                pass


print max_product
```

Comment: Why isn't it working?  Point out parts in the code.  What is the output?  What is the *expected* output?

Comment: @tim: Well, Project euler expects to find the max product. If you find it, put in the box and verify. My output is 51267216 but its not correct.

Comment: Unless you have a more specific question or problem you may have more luck on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you perhaps forgetting that there are **two** diagonal directions?